# Save features from hidden layers from an auto-encoder model using keras in runtime

Tags: python, keras, feature-extraction, autoencoder

I am training an auto-encoder model and  want to save the features of each image during runtime from encoder part and use it later for feature matching.

My model structure is-

```
train_data_dir = '/train'
test_data_dir = '/test'
nb_train_samples = 100
nb_validation_samples = 25
nb_epoch = 2
batch_size = 5
input_img = Input(shape=( img_width, img_height,3))

x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu',padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded = Conv2D(3, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)
autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')

def fixed_generator(generator):
    for batch in generator:
        yield (batch, batch)

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)
# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for testing:
# only rescaling
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_data_dir,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode=None)
#print(type(train_generator))
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        test_data_dir,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode=None)

autoencoder.fit_generator(
        fixed_generator(train_generator),
        epochs=nb_epoch,
        samples_per_epoch=nb_train_samples,
        validation_data=fixed_generator(test_generator),
        validation_steps=nb_validation_samples
        )
```

How can i save the features from encoder part during model fit. Is there any way, please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save the features from a autoencoder model, first you need to load the model and extract the last encoder layer from the model.

Here is the code to extract the layers of an encoder and save the features for an image:

```
autoencoder= load_model('model_weights.h5')
encoder = Model(autoencoder.input, autoencoder.layers[-1].output)

# Read your input image for which you need to extract features

img = cv2.imread(img)
newimg = cv2.resize(img,(512,512))
encoded_imgs = encoder.predict(newimg[None])[0]

# Save your features as an numpy array

np.save('features.npy', encoded_imgs)
```

After saving your feature for an input image you need to find the euclidean distance for feature matching.

```
file = 'sample.npy'
file = np.load(file)
file1 = "features.npy"
file1 = np.load(file1)
distance = np.linalg.norm(file-file1)
print(distance)
```

This code will extract the features from an image and calculate the distance between two numpy arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Keras Functional API is the keyword, there is even a very insightful [blog post](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html) on autoencoders.

Here are the key points of the example taken from the blog post:

```
input_img = Input(shape=(784,))
encoded = Dense(encoding_dim, activation='relu')(input_img)
decoded = Dense(784, activation='sigmoid')(encoded)
# this model maps an input to its reconstruction
autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
# this model maps an input to its encoded representation
encoder = Model(input_img, encoded)
```

Now you can put the `autoencoder.fit(...,epochs=1)` method into a for-loop and look at the encoded representation with `encoder.predict(your_data)` to save the features.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar task with text data, I am extracting the encoder from a trained model and saving it out. I load the encoder and do `encoder.predict(input_sample)` to generate encoded vector (for retrieval purpose). However every time I load and predict the output varies (keeping the same input). Is this behavior normal?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
encoder = Model(input_img , encoded)
```

instead of

```
encoder = Model(autoencoder.input, autoencoder.layers[-1].output)
```

because autoencoder.layers[-1].output means the decoder layer which is the reconstructed original image